# How to inflate view in list view for odd and even position

Tags: android, xml, android-arrayadapter

How to inflate view in list view for odd and even position.I want to show left align xml in even position and right align xml to odd position.

```
This is my code:  

 public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup parent)
{
    LayoutInflater inflator = context.getLayoutInflater();
    if ((position % 2) == 0) {

         rowView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.chatbubble, null, true);

        TextView txtv_msg;
        txtv_msg = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.message_text);
        txtv_msg.setText(""+menus[position]);
    }
    else {
        rowView1 = inflator.inflate(R.layout.chatbubble1, null, true);

        TextView txtv_msg;
        txtv_msg = (TextView) rowView1.findViewById(R.id.message_text);
        txtv_msg.setText(""+menus[position]);

    }

    return rowView;
}
```

but for all position my data items are left align .

```
This is my xml  :
for left :
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
      <LinearLayout   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:id="@+id/bubble_layout_parent"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_margin="10dp"
       android:padding="5dp">

    <LinearLayout
     android:id="@+id/bubble_layout"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:background="@drawable/bubble1">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/message_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxEms="12"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Hi! new message"
        android:textColor="@android:color/primary_text_light" />
   </LinearLayout>

  </LinearLayout>

  for right :
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:id="@+id/bubble_layout_parent"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_margin="10dp"
      android:padding="5dp"
      android:layout_gravity="right">

    <LinearLayout
     android:id="@+id/bubble_layout"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:background="@drawable/bubble1">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/message_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxEms="12"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Hi! new message"
        android:textColor="@android:color/primary_text_light" />
       </LinearLayout>

       </LinearLayout>
```

I am new to android development please help.

Comment: It is left because you have `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` on parent layout. Try changing that to `match_parent` and also set `layout_gravity` on bubble layout not parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `override` these two `base adapter` methods

```
@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
  return 2;
} 


@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
  //return 0 or 1 according to your view
}
```

and in `getView()`

```
int type = getItemViewType(position);
```

and inflate your view according to `type`.
you can follow this simplifies [example](http://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2014/08/android-listview-with-multiple-row.html) as well.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your adapter's `getView()` method. It always returns `rowView` which is `left aligned XML`.

**Solution:**

1. Rename adapter's `getView()` parameter `view` as `rowView`.
2. In your `else` condition `inflate` layout `R.layout.chatbubble1` to `rowView` instead of `rowView1` and also change `rowView1.findViewById()` to `rowView.findViewById()`.

**Here is the complete working code:**

```
public View getView(final int position, View rowView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    LayoutInflater inflator = context.getLayoutInflater();
    if ((position % 2) == 0) {
        rowView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.chatbubble, null, true);

        TextView txtv_msg;
        txtv_msg = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.message_text);
        txtv_msg.setText("" + menus[position]);
    }
    else {
        rowView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.chatbubble1, null, true);

        TextView txtv_msg;
        txtv_msg = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.message_text);
        txtv_msg.setText("" + menus[position]);

    }

    return rowView;
}
```

Hope this will help~